# Which one is 10?

Tags: wordplay, english

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

---

If renovating = 1,
showtime = 2,
axis = 6 and
evening = 9,

then which of the following = 10 (and why):

cash, cheque, dollar, financial, monetary, teller?

Comment: For once a puzzle that I can solve! :-p Too bad other people solved it before me… We need more like this, though! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is...

> Monetary

Because...

> Each word contains the word of the numbers in reverse:
>  r**eno**vating, sh**owt**ime, a**xis**, ev**enin**g, and mo**net**ary

Comment: Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!