Arrange yourselves in a more interesting order
The items below are arranged in alphabetical order.  However, there is a more interesting way to order them.

athletics commissioner

attendance metrics

bronze rowers

info URL

lacrosse venue

mezzanine level

network broadcast

Paris IX arrondissement

plinth reevaluation

travel event

weightlifting competition

Wi-Fi vendor


A related question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124681/which-one-is-10

We can arrange these items in

 numerical order from 0 to 11

Like

 bronze rowers
 athletics commissioner
 network broadcast
 plinth reevaluation
 info URL
 Wi-Fi vendor
 Paris IX arrondissement
 lacrosse venue
 weightlifting competition
 mezzanine level
 attendance metrics
 travel event

