Just got a new job... huh?
(This is just a story, not actually real... obviously.)
My name is Parangel. I recently got a new job at the office of Pazlo. I was stoked to see what that job was, but to my dismay, it was ordering files in a file cabinet.
Ah well. They said every job here would be great, so I guess I should be optimistic! So the day comes for my first shift, and I see my boss, who tells me that I need to put some files in order.
'But not in alphabetical order, no!'
'You need to put these files in a logical order; that's what Pazlo is for!'
I can't see any reason why that'd be useful, but the boss seemed pretty confident about it. Ah well. 'I think it'll be easy,' I thought, as I walked over to the cabinet.
I really do have to make this count. Of course, that won't be easy and all, with all these curveballs to my usual understanding of work...
How do I order these ten eight-letter words in a logical order?
FIREBALL
FIXATION
FLURRIED
KINETICS
NIGHTJAR
OENOLOGY
SELENIUM
SNEERING
THREATEN
TROOPERS


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

A related question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/127728/arrange-yourselves-in-a-more-interesting-order

Another related question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124681/which-one-is-10

The logical order you're looking for is

 SNEERING 
 TROOPERS 
 THREATEN 
 FLURRIED 
 FIREBALL 
 FIXATION 
 SELENIUM 
 NIGHTJAR 
 KINETICS 
 OENOLOGY

This is because

 each word starts with a number between one and ten, with a single letter that has been changed. A logical way to order the words would therefore be by sorting the numbers from one to ten:


 SNEERING: ONE 
TROOPERS: TWO 
THREATEN: THREE 
FLURRIED: FOUR 
FIREBALL: FIVE 
FIXATION: SIX 
SELENIUM: SEVEN 
NIGHTJAR: EIGHT 
KINETICS: NINE 
OENOLOGY: TEN


Exactly right! There was a clue there, by 'make this count' and all. Otherwise, quite good!

@PolygonPotpourri we often use "ROT13" to hide clues/hints in comments. There are browser extensions that can do this from the right click menu. ROT13 example "znxr guvf pbhag"
